# sed regex Invalid Range error for unicode range

Tags: regex, sed, unicode, unicode-range

```
    | sed 's/[\u0600-\u06FF]/ & /g'  \
```

I am getting the following error for the above expression.

sed: -e expression #1, char 22: Invalid range end

Although I've verified that the expression is correct, I don't understand why this is still an invalid range. Any suggestions?

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196780/is-there-an-alternative-to-sed-that-supports-unicode and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442225/match-language-range-in-shell-sed-or-awk